# how to get detail from a prepareCall when it gets a row of an array

Tags: java, mysql, callable-statement

I have a program that connects to Db, using prepareCall. there is a function that browse some element from Db.  this is part of this function:

```
Resource f = new Resource();
        if (rs.next()) {
            f.setAreaSrl(rs.getInt(1));
            f.setAreaId(rs.getInt(2));
            f.setAreaName(rs.getString(3));
            f.setCenterX(rs.getFloat(4));
            f.setCenterY(rs.getFloat(5));
            f.setCenterZ(rs.getFloat(6));

        }
        return f;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "problem in accessing DB");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

and I have the folloing code in java:

```
Resource mzone = new Resource();
          mzone.getOneEntityBase("areasrl=i");
```

that will give me a row of table. how can i access to them, element by element?

I want to do some calculation by this numbers, so i need to have them separately.

I have found some way to do it, but it doesn't work.

```
Resource mzone = new ResourceAreaZone();
          mzone.getOneEntityBase("areasrl=1");
          String name = mzone.getAreaName();              
          centerX = (int) mzone.getCenterX();
```

Comment: Post the code of your `Resource`

Comment: Hi
    Resourse is only the name of object.

it has some parameter which show where the resource is located.

Comment: I did not write this program. this program is written by somebody else. and I just wanna use it. 
I just want to use the parameter, for example what is the CenterX and CenterY of the parameter to calculate the distance.

Comment: OK, so you are expecting us to help you without seeing any code? Sorry but that's unlikely to work... ;-)

Comment: No, I just don't know which part of it do u mean?